# Methods of getting a user's current client side date and time in different areas

Tags: java, javascript

We have applications that use servers in a central location that have their own server time. We have users covering the entire world. Every time we need to handle a page print, or need to calculate age (to the day) or anything else that needs client time we are sending the client time over the wire from the browser and storing that in a Date object in java and working with it there.

Sometimes we just do it in JavaScript on the client's side if it is a unique case that doesn't need to be repeated. It would be nice to standardize a way of sending date and time over the wire one time only and using that on the server. I was thinking of just keeping a variable in the session and using the time since the session was created.

I am curious if anyone else has dealt with this and come up with a clever way of handling this, I am sure we are not the first people to deal with this little annoyance.

It is also possible that just sending the client date when needed actually IS the best way to do this instead of trying to over-complicate something that is relatively simple. I am leaning a little more towards that right now. That would mean I basically do nothing else... which I am seldom opposed to doing =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely want to avoid sending the client's current time every time he sends a requests that requires it, which is not very costly in computing time nor in bandwith IMO, why not retrieve the client's timezone once and store it in the session, and then use it to compute the time on the server side every time you need it?

It seems easier to me than using the time since the session was created, and cleaner as well.

You can retrieve the timezone offset on the client side using:

```
dateObj.getTimezoneOffset()
```

which returns the offset of the client's timezone in minutes (For example, if your time zone is UTC+10 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), -600 will be returned).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset for more details.